# In Python, why does setting an indexed item of a property-generated object update the base object, but other changes do not

Tags: python, object, properties

I have some objects which have attributes that can be accessed directly through properties, or less directly through a secondary object, which is generated by another property.  As an example consider the Person and Pet classes below:

```
class Pet():
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = {'age': 0,
                      'dimensions': [0, 0, 0],
                      'resources': {'food': True, 'water': True}}

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._dict.get(item, None)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dict[key] = value


class Person():
    def __init__(self):

        self._pets_age = 1
        self._pet_dim = [1, 1, 1]
        self._resources = {'food': False, 'water': False}

    @property
    def pets_age(self):
        return self._pets_age

    @pets_age.setter
    def pets_age(self, years):
        self._pets_age = years

    @property
    def pets_dimensions(self):
        return self._pet_dim

    @pets_dimensions.setter
    def pets_dimensions(self, val):
        self._pet_dim = val

    @property
    def resources(self):
        return self._resources

    @resources.setter
    def resources(self, val):
        self._resources.update(val)

    @property
    def pet(self):

        pet = Pet()
        pet['age'] = self._pets_age
        pet['dimensions'] = self._pet_dim
        pet['resources'] = self._resources

        return pet

    @pet.setter
    def pet(self, p):
        print('Person.pet setter called')

        self._pets_age = p._dict['age']
        self._pet_dim = p._dict['dimensions']
        self._resources = p._dict['resources']


if __name__ == '__main__':

    me = Person()

    #Set the pet's age
    me.pets_age = 8

    #Get age through property
    print('Pet Age: {}'.format(me.pet['age']))

    #Set different age through property
    me.pet['age'] = 10

    #Get the pet age again...
    print('Pet age (want it to be 10): {}'.format(me.pets_age))

    me._pet_dim = [3, 4, 5]
    print('Pet Dimensions: {}'.format(me.pet['dimensions']))

    me.pet['dimensions'][0] = 7

    print('Pet Dimensions (wanting [7, 4, 5]): {}'.format(me.pets_dimensions))

    me.pet['dimensions'] = [8, 4, 5]

    print('Pet Dimensions (wanting [8, 4, 5]): {}'.format(me.pets_dimensions))

    me.resources = {'food': True, 'water': True}
    me.pet['resources']['food'] = False

    print('Pet Resources (want food=False, water=True): {}'.format(me.pet['resources']))

    me.pet['resources'] = {'food': False, 'water': False}

    print('Pet Resources (want food=False, water=False): {}'.format(me.pet['resources']))
```

And here is the result of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section

```
Pet Age: 8
Pet age (want it to be 10): 8
Pet Dimensions: [3, 4, 5]
Pet Dimensions (wanting [7, 4, 5]): [7, 4, 5]
Pet Dimensions (wanting [8, 4, 5]): [7, 4, 5]
Pet Resources (want food=False, water=True): {'food': False, 'water': True}
Pet Resources (want food=False, water=False): {'food': False, 'water': True}
```

My main conundrum is demonstrated in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` section.  When I do `person.pet`, the `Person.pet` property getter is called resulting in an instance of `Pet` being generated.  I have `Pet` set up like a dictionary where data is accessed with `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` (like `pet['age']`) and the data is stored within in `Pet._dict`.  In my real data I have reasons for this - the class does other things besides hold a dictionary.  The conundrum is what happens when I do `person.pet['age'] = 10`?  In this situation, a pet object is generated on the fly and it's age item is set to `10`.  That's it.  There is nothing in this logic to set the pet back to the person, which would call the `Person.pet` property setter function and store the pet's age in `Person._pets_age`.

While this is the behavior which bit me, this is only the beginning.

The reason this bit me is that a lot of my data was lists and I was modifying specific indexes of the lists.  `The Pet['dimensions']` item and `Pet['resources']` both behave this way.  When `person.pet['dimensions'][0] = 7` is called, the pet object is generated from the `Person.pet` property getter, the `__getitem__` method translates the `pet['dimensions']` call into `pet._dict['dimensions']` which returns the `[3, 4, 5]` list (per the example code), and the `[0]` list index is used to change the list to `[7, 4, 5]`, oh man.... I just figured this whole thing out.  I'll explain in the Answer section.

So the gist of the problem is that for individual numbers like age the changes to pet don't affect person, but for containers like lists and dicts, the changes happen to person as well.  I thought the only way the changes would propagate back is through the person.pet setter, but I confirmed that the setter is never getting called.

Answer (score 0):

For the list and dictionary the references to them are just aliases to their memory location.  When the Pet instance is generated it is handed the references to the `dimensions` list and `resources` dictionary.  When the list and dictionary are updated as members of `pet`, the underlying memory location is updated, which is also being referred to by `person`.  This the list and dictionary are effectively shared by the `person` and the `pet` and changes to either affect the same memory.  If copies of the list or dictionary were generated and passed to the Pet, no changes to the `pet` would have any affect on the person.

I believe this reference passing type behavior occurs for all mutable types, which include `list`, `dict`, `set`, and other containers that can be changed in place, as opposed to immutable types like `int`, `float`, `str`, `tuple`, and `frozenset`.

For modifications to the `pet` to propagate to the `person`, code like the following must be used.

```
pet = person.pet
pet.age = 10
person.pet = pet
```

I suppose this is an instance of "explicit is better than implicit".

Or the design should be changed such that `pet` is stored persistently in `person` and the `pet`'s attributes are referenced directly by the `Person` properties.  This would follow both "simple is better than complex" and "beautiful is better than ugly".

Sorry for cluttering the internet with my "aha!" moments here.  I thought I was past these variable aliasing problems, but this situation was complicated enough to hide the core issue from me (made much more complicated by subclassing and inherited properties in my actual code).  I thought property was doing some magic when it really wasn't.  Hopefully this helps someone!